# Repeat row headers for one big row with text spanning multiple pages

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to repeat the row headers in a very simple tablix, where I have one header row and a detail row, which will constist of only one entry. This entry, however, is a possibly long text, and when it is larger than one page, the header won't be repeated, even though I set the `RepeatOnNewPage`, `KeepWithGroup` and `FixedData` to `TRUE` in advanced mode.

I googled around and found [this blog post](http://blogs.objectsharp.com/post/2013/01/09/SSRS-and-Column-Headers.aspx) in which it is recommended to add a dummy column group, which didn't work either.

I now followed eestein's suggestion and have the following results:
PDF: [image: PDF]
BIDS: [image: BIDS]

Comment: +1 interesting question, I'm not sure if there *is* a solution though...

Comment: You remembered to select the static content in Row groups, right?

Answer (score 1):

I think I understood your problem.
You don't have any groups and want to repeat the header, correct?

If so, I've done that several times and this is what you should do:

You need to create a dummy group (as you've read)

1. Right click your details and add a parent row group
2. Group it by "A", for instance.
3. Check Add a header.
4. On the header row you just added paste your original header and then
   remove the original one

Now you can set those properties you mentioned using advanced mode and selecting your header's static content.

Images below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks eestein, but that's not my problem. My problem is not that I don't have any groups (I think I could just add a "Details"-group), but rather that my single entry in the tablix has so much text that it spreads across multiple pages, where the "normal" repeat-parameters don't help

Comment: @Harry Can you post an image of what's happening? For what you explained what I proposed should solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, sure. 
This is what it looks like in the PDF: http://s8.postimage.org/qq2w3sout/PDF.png
This is what it looks like in BIDS: http://s2.postimage.org/g62bt0qrd/Report.png

I also set the GroupExpressions as ="A", in case you wonder.

Comment: @Harry I can't open this website here. Update your post with your image using SO's image upload tool.

Comment: I can't post them directly because I need 10 reputation in order to do that -.- Could you please upvote my question? Then I should be able to do that. Don't know if it helps, but uploaded the images on imageshack as well - PDF: http://imageshack.us/a/img233/9692/pdfc.png BIDS: http://imageshack.us/a/img845/8597/reportjl.png

Comment: @Harry just did, upload to SO, because I can't access imageshack as well.

Comment: just edited the initial post and embedded the screenshots - hope you can see them now? Otherwise you have to explain me, how uploading to SO works, didn't find that in the FAQ :-)

Comment: @Harry Click on the image icon, select "from my computer" and then upload. Don't use the imageshack link.

Comment: @Harry not a problem xD  I assume you are grouping Group1 by something like "A", right?

Comment: @Harry Ok, I really don't know what your problem is, but I would try deleting the tablix and creating another. Believe me, SSRS has some strange, misterious bugs... I have the same scenario as yours and I've done this several times, as I said. Try to look for something in your machine. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this same question (since I'm having the same issue) to [MS Forum](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d32ad5b8-ef99-4915-a715-1e50145b7603/column-headers-do-not-repeat-when-exported-to-pdf-for-long-rows-or-grouping-rows?forum=sqlreportingservices) and got a reply from TechNet Community Support person. For PDF Exports, it is apparently by design that long rows spanning multiple pages do not render the repeated Column Headers. It seems that the column headers are tied to the grouping.

A scenario that can be helped is when a grouping is spanning multiple pages, but the details are not. The workaround is to break the parent grouping and use HideDuplicates property to fake the grouping, visually.

Below is a rudimentary visualization of actual grouping vs. the fake grouping workaround.

```
            When using grouping, the rows are merged,
_______  <- the blank area is part of the merged rows.
Group1 | Row1 Col1 | Row1 Col2
_______| Row2 Col1 | Row2 Col2
Group2 | Row3 Col1 | Row3 Col2
       | Row4 Col1 | Row4 Col2
```

vs

```
When using HideDuplicates, all rows are printed, it simply hidden or blank.
Also, you have to hide all borders or have border around all of those cells.
Group1   | Row1 Col1 | Row1 Col2
[hidden] | Row2 Col1 | Row2 Col2
Group2   | Row3 Col1 | Row3 Col2
         | Row4 Col1 | Row4 Col2
```

A second, better work-around is to turn off the repeat header feature and copy the Cells to the Header. You can hide them on the first page. It actually works quite well.